# In clojure, how do you pass a list to a parameterized function (&more)

Tags: rest, clojure, parameterized

Say I have function:

```
(defn foo [something & otherthings]
  (println something)
  (println otherthings))
```

evaluating

```
(foo "ack" "moo" "boo")
```

gives me :

```
ack                                                               
(moo boo)
```

what if I want to call foo with a list?

```
(foo "ack" (list "moo" "boo"))
```

and get

```
ack                                                            
(moo boo)
```

instead of

```
ack                                            
((moo boo))
```

Is there any way to do that without changing foo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `apply`:

```
(apply foo "ack" (list "moo" "boo"))
```